# Software for adjusting the velocity curve of a MIDI controller in Linux

Tags: linux, music-production

I use my Yamaha CLP330 digital piano as a MIDI controller. The problem is that the volume of the sound is too low when I play on the piano. But using software controllers the sound is normal. So it seems that the velocity value on my digital piano is set too low. I have Also set the touch on the piano to soft. I use Ubuntu Studio on my computer. Is there any software for linux for adjusting the velocity curve in realtime?

Comment: Adjust to a fixed value or adjust to a controllable value?

Comment: If by fixed value you mean a preset value and by controllable you mean customizable, the second one is exactly what I need. But if you know a software which allows me to set the velocity curve to a preset value, please let me know.

Comment: I was thinking of [Midish filter](http://www.midish.org/manual.html#section_6_1) which would probably allow changing it to any fixed value if you know the value before. Never used it myself, though